# Uploading Image from WebAPi [ Azure Mobile APP] to Folder in Azure Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have created an Azure Mobile App & and Azure Web App. What I need to do is upload image from mobile using webapi endpoint of the Azure Mobile APP and Upload it to a folder inside my Azure Web App.

I am able to get the image in my api using `HTTpContext` so I can save it inside a folder in the webapi itself but it is not what I need. I have no idea how to save it to folder inside my Web App. But API and WebAPP have same resource group.

Please point me in the right direction as to how it can be done.

Comment: I would suggest going for Azure blob storage for this. By using blob storage, 1. You can offload the load from your server 2. the resource/image will be available for any services. You can protect your resources by making it private in the blob container and then use the signed url to access the blob resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am able to get the image in my api using HTTpContext so I can save it inside a folder in the webapi itself but it is not what I need. I have no idea how to save it to folder inside my Web App. But API and WebAPP have same resource group.

As [Azure-Web-App-sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox) states about File System Restrictions/Considerations:

> **Every Azure Web App has a home directory (`d:\home`) stored/backed by Azure Storage**. This network share is where applications store their content. This directory is available for the sandbox with read/write access.

So for a specific Azure Web App, the Azure Web App content is stored on Azure Storage and is shared among multiple instances. But it does not shared between different web apps.

For uploading file(s) from your mobile app to azure web app, you could leverage the **VFS API** under [KUDU REST API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API) as follows:

```
PUT /api/vfs/{path}
//Puts a file at path.

PUT /api/vfs/{path}/
//Creates a directory at path. The path can be nested, e.g. `folder1/folder2`.
```

**Note:** You need to use the basic authentication. Detailed code snippet, you could follow [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gabeshapiro/2017/01/01/samples-for-using-the-azure-app-service-kudu-rest-api-to-programmatically-manage-files-in-your-site/).

Additionally, as rahicks pointed out that you could directly upload your resources into a central data storage, then they would be accessed in your multiple applications. And you could leverage [Azure Storage Client Library for .NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/) and directly upload images to your blob storage. Also, you could leverage the storage client library in your azure web app for reading/writing your resources. Detailed tutorials, you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs). Moreover, you could use [Azure Storage Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer) to manage your storage resources.

Answer (score 0):

```
///... check rest of request
///... define image path @"image/img1"
///... persist entity with image path
path = Server.MapPath(imagePath);
if(!System.IO.File.Exists(path)) 
     file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path));
```

If you need more help here is a step by step. It's a bit old, but should do the trick.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-upload-image-and-save-image-in-project-folder-in-mvc1

Update:
Since you need to share between servers it would be best to set up a blob storage account for this. Here is a walkthrough on that:

https://www.codeproject.com/articles/490178/how-to-use-azure-blob-storage-with-azure-web-sites

Comment: Hi rahicks.. In the article you shared , image is being shared on the same server in the same application . What i need to do is to save image into different server i.e from MobileApp xyz.azurewebsites.net to abc.azurewebsites.net/Images....

Comment: You best bet in that case is blob storage. I will update and post a few links for that. If you really want to use the server approach you can it just is going to expose those images publicly.